# How to get Chrome Browser on iOS to open map link?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

On iOS (iPad Pro) Safari, when I click on the following web link in a web page, a prompt appears asking if I want to open in Apple Maps:

http://maps.apple.com/?q=40.7410895,-73.9896979

On a PC, it automatically redirects to https://www.google.com/maps?q=40.7410895,-73.9896979

If however I go to the same webpage and click the link in iOS (iPad Pro) Chrome browser, a new tab opens for about 0.5 seconds and closes again.

Is that a Chrome bug? It used to work when I checked about 6 months ago.

EDIT:

Actually, my mistake, it seems to work on a normal HTML link like on this page. I should have said it just doesn't work like it used to when I click a div with the following:

```
onclick='window.open("http://maps.apple.com/?q=40.7410895,-73.9896979", "_blank")'
```

Is that a Chrome bug (relating to Javascript)?